# What is the biblical basis for Christians quitting their jobs?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, sect

Recently upon travelling from university I came across a fairly new Christian sect called [Jesus Christians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Christians).

They were handing out DVD's which had a QR code linking to a Youtube channel called [A Voice In The Desert](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGK3xwxFRFvYyXAtDBShlMQ).

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAXH_HGJDPw&t=322s), they claim that the three steps to revival in Christianity are as follows:

1. Quit your job
2. Sell everything
3. Preach the Gospel

I know in the Gospels Jesus asks His disciples to give up certain things, and there is at least one of each occurrence of each of the above in the Gospels but has Jesus actually commanded us to do the same or was it directed to the Disciples at the time?

Moreover; what does the rest of the Bible teach about giving up jobs for Jesus? From my understanding Paul worked very hard as a tent maker as a means to support himself in his ministry, I also understand that a lawyer was mentioned in the passage below.

> Bring Zenas the lawyer and Apollos on their journey diligently, that nothing be wanting unto them. **Titus 3:13 (NIV)**

What is the biblical basis for Christians quitting their jobs for their salvation?

Comment: What do these "Jesus Christians" say is the biblical basis for their claims? If they don't give one, then that tells you a lot about their claims.

Comment: I'll catch up with one soon to see what they have to teach, they're pretty mysterious online..

Answer (score 3):

## Diligence and not worshiping money

There is much Scriptural basis both for being diligent in work:

> [1 Cor. 4:12](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=4&l=12-#x) And we labour, working with our own hands.

and not worshiping mammon (money):

> [Matttew 6:24](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=6&l=24-#x) No man can serve two masters. For either he will hate the one, and love the other: or he will sustain the one, and despise the other. You cannot serve God and mammon.

## Voluntary poverty

Voluntary poverty is one of the three [evangelical counsels](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32847) ("Good actions that are not prescribed by any law"); the two other evangelical counsels being chastity and obedience. The evangelical counsels are what brothers and nuns solemnly vow to practice their entire lives.

> [St. Matthew 19:21](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=19&l=21-#x) Jesus saith to him: If thou wilt be perfect, go sell what thou hast, and give to the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come, follow me.

## Work as an excuse not to follow Jesus

The [parable](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11460a.htm) of the great supper ([St. Luke 14:15](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=14&l=15-#x)-24) illustrates those using work as an excuse not the follow Jesus; when the supper was ready, the invited guests

> began all at once to make excuse. The first said to him: I have bought a farm and I must needs go out and see it. I pray thee, hold me excused. And another said: I have bought five yoke of oxen and I go to try them. I pray thee, hold me excused. [vv. 18-19]

---

<sup>Also, that video insinuates, @4:33 ff., that Catholic priests should quit their divine duty of offering the Holy Sacrifice of the Mass; thus, these "Jesus Christians" appear to be an anti-Catholic sect.</sup>